# How to get yesterday date in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I want yesterday date in my script, how to get it in JMeter scripts.

```
Ex ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd)}
```

I am using current time 
How to get decrease the date with previous date
I tried with

```
 ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd)} - 1
```

But not worked

Answer (score 3):

You can use [__timeShift](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function to get yesterday:

```
${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,now,-P1D,yesterday)}
```

> The timeShift function returns a date in the given format with the specified amount of seconds, minutes, hours, days or months added

This will also save value in JMeter variable `yesterday` accessible later using `${yesterday}

Comment: really tank you very much to save my time to spend on this issue